# Statistics followed by Neutrinos

Tags: particle-physics, neutrinos

What does the neutrino particles follow- Dirac or Majorana Statistics?

Comment: One questions per question. Seriously. And in any case [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/81911/how-does-cosmology-constrain-the-number-of-neutrino-species) is less than a day old.

Comment: @dmckee I didn't get you. What are talking about and why is my question edited in such a way that the cardinal thing I want to focus on is missed?

Comment: You asked two question in one "question". That is strongly discouraged. Because one of them was a duplicate (as linked above) I removed that element of the question rather than simply closing the whole thing.

Answer (score 2):

Neutrinos follow Fermi-Dirac statistics; there is no such thing as Majorana statistics.

I think you meant to ask whether neutrinos are Dirac or Majorana particles. That is still an open question.